# How can I set DataTemplate to a ContentControl in a PageResource in Windows Universal App 10?

Tags: mvvm, visual-studio-2015, uwp

How can I set DataTemplate to a ContentControl in a PageResource? I would like to display a UserControl in my ContentControl and I want use the ContentControl like a navigation region. So it can change the UserControls what are displayed in it.

I have a Shell.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:View="using:MyProject.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="using:MyProject.ViewModel">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:ShellViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate>
             <View:MyUserControlViewModel1 />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
             <View:MyUserControlViewModel2 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}">
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

My Shell's view model is:

```
namespace MyProject.ShellViewModel
{
    class ShellViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Fields

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;
        private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
        private List<IPageViewModel> _pageViewModels;

        #endregion

        #region Properties / Commands

        public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                {
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();
                }
                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
        {
            get { return _currentPageViewModel; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
                {
                    _currentPageViewModel = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            PageViewModels.Add(new MyUserControlViewModel1());
            PageViewModels.Add(new MyUserControlViewModel2());

            CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I tried set Page.Resource like below from this link: [Window vs Page vs UserControl for WPF navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation)

```
<Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
         <local:HomeView /> <!-- This is a UserControl -->
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
         <local:ProductsView /> <!-- This is a UserControl -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
```

But these use another namespaces and it doesn't work for me because my app is a Windows 10 Universal App and there is no DataType attribute for the DataTemplate for example.

I am trying to make my application using MVVM pattern (if it was not obiously from the code snippets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by creating a class derived from `DataTemplateSelector`.

In this class you can override `SelectTemplateCore` method, that will return the `DataTemplate` you need based on the data type. To make all this more auto-magical, you can set the key of each template to match the name of the class and then search for the resource with that name retrieved using `GetType().Name`.

To be able to provide specific implementations on different levels, you can walk up the tree using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` until the matching resource is found and use `Application.Current.Resources[ typeName ]` as fallback.

To use your custom template selector, just set it to `ContentTemplateSelector` property of the `ContentControl`.

**Example**

Here is the sample implementation of an `AutoDataTemplateSelector`

```cs
public class AutoDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore( object item ) => GetTemplateForItem( item, null );

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore( object item, DependencyObject container ) => GetTemplateForItem( item, container );

    private DataTemplate GetTemplateForItem( object item, DependencyObject container )
    {
        if ( item != null )
        {
            var viewModelTypeName = item.GetType().Name;
            var dataTemplateInTree = FindResourceKeyUpTree( viewModelTypeName, container );
            //return or default to Application resource
            return dataTemplateInTree ?? ( DataTemplate )Application.Current.Resources[ viewModelTypeName ];
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find the resources up the tree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceKey">Key to find</param>
    /// <param name="container">Current container</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private DataTemplate FindResourceKeyUpTree( string resourceKey, DependencyObject container )
    {
        var frameworkElement = container as FrameworkElement;
        if ( frameworkElement != null )
        {
            if ( frameworkElement.Resources.ContainsKey( resourceKey ) )
            {
                return frameworkElement.Resources[ resourceKey ] as DataTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                return FindResourceKeyUpTree( resourceKey, VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( frameworkElement ) );
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can now instantiate it as a resource and create resources for each type of ViewModel you use

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:AutoDataTemplateSelector x:Key="AutoDataTemplateSelector" />

    <!-- sample viewmodel data templates -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RedViewModel">
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BlueViewModel">
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

And now you can use it with the `ContentControl` as follows:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AutoDataTemplateSelector}"
   Content="{x:Bind CurrentViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I have put the [sample solution on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/AutoDataTemplateSelector)