# Changing page from another page in main window wpf mvvm c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using mvvmlight framework for wpf.
I have main window where I put my frame (firstLoadedPage is just an example):

```
        <Frame Source="firstLoadedPage" />
```

I want to change my page to another one when I click button in

> first loaded page

but I have no idea how can I achieve it.
I've tried bind property like this to frame source:

```
public static string _myFrameSourcePath = firstLoadedPage
public string MyFrameSourcePath
{
    get { return _myFrameSourcePath; }
    set {
       _myFrameSourcePath = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("MyFrameSourcePath");
    }
}
```

and then change value of _myFrameSourcePath when I click button in firstLoadedPage. It doesn't work so I tried change MyFrameSourcePath to static and then change value of MyFrameSourcePath instead of _myFrameSourcePath in Page. It also doesn't work.

Can somebody tell me how can I change my page placed in frame source in MainWindow when I click button inside this page to change current page to another?

Comment: When you write `<Frame Source="firstLoadedPage" />`, are you missing a binding here? It should be something like `<Frame Source="{Binding MyFrameSourcePath}" />`. Also, be sure you're setting the public `MyFrameSourcePath` property which will also call the property change notification, not the private `_myFrameSourcePath`. On an related note, I'm not sure if it's the same thing but I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216068/302677) a while back about navigating using MVVM... perhaps it will help you get going in the right direction?

Comment: The point is that was just an example. I binded Souce from Frame before with property implemented in MainWindowViewModel. I want to override this property from MainWindowViewModel by clicking button in MyPage.xaml, this shoulda change my uri path in Source, but it doesnt work even for static variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. Below is a sample Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock>Outside area of frame</TextBlock>
        <Frame Name="FrameWithinGrid"  Source="{Binding FrameSource}">
        </Frame>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Height="23" Margin="114,12,25,0" Command="{Binding GoToCommand}"   
            VerticalAlignment="Top" >Navigate to Msdn
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

In Your ViewModel , some sample codes for example:

```
      private Uri _frameSource = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
      public Uri FrameSource
      {
         get { return _frameSource;}

         set
         {
            _frameSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FrameSource");
         }
      }

      public ICommand GoToCommand
      {
         get
         {
            return new DelegateCommand(ExecuteGoTo);
         }
      }

      private void ExecuteGoTo()
      {
         FrameSource = new Uri("http://www.msdn.com", UriKind.Absolute);
      }
```

Thats all. Make sure your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged. If you are using MVVM Light, change the DelegateCommand to RelayCommand

Comment: I want to do something similar to your answer, NoahV, but in your solution I am changing page in window.xaml using button in this window.xaml. I want to change page by clicking button in page.xaml what should change property URI in my windowviewmodel.

Comment: You should create a corresponding view model for page.xml, set the Command of the button to be for eg ExecuteCommand, in that view model for page.xml, declare ICommand as above