# How to switch between a user control and a wpf page in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, report

Good day coders

Its my first time using Pages in C#. I am struggling with something really silly that is preventing me from getting my work done. How to a switch from a user control/windows form to a page.

I tried the following:

```
NavigationService navService = NavigationService
             .GetNavigationService(this); 

            navService.Navigate =  (new
             System.Uri("Page2.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Look into MVVM, your answer lies there.

Comment: Does something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216068/302677) help you out?