# How to navigate from a main window to other user control without using mvvm in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I want to navigate from main window to other user control which is present in the views folder. I am not using mvvm model. Is it possible to navigate

Comment: What is `min window` and what you meant by navigate to user control? are you looking for loading an user control in the main window? Please be specific while come up with a question

Comment: I have a separate user control ('Example.xaml') and i have a button in Mainwindow.xaml. Onclick of a button i want to navigate to 'Example.xaml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that question you asked is not complete, but I'll try to answer.

So you have window, and some content inside of it, and that's **MainWindow** i suppose. You want to change content of main window to contain your user control which is also defined in **separate file**. So, you can't do this in the way you described.

**UserControl** is only a control that window can contain, so basicaly you need something like placeholder in your window to change content dynamically like web browser navigation, and that's what **Frame** is.

**Frame** is control that helps to provide navigation between pages. You can create **Frame** inside your **MainWindow** and also create some pages. Then you will be able to implement switching between pages in your frame using **Frame.Navigate()** method.

Here is similar question described, please take look:

[Window vs Page vs UserControl for WPF navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation)

Also there is a good article that may help you:

http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation