# In a WPF application using Visual Studio, how can I bind a usercontrol to a usercontrol variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm not sure if I asked the question correctly, because I am not finding the answer by searching the internet. I am creating a **wizard window**. I have a window that has a title at the top and buttons at the bottom that will stay there throughout changing the pages. So in the `xaml.cs` for the window, I have a list of `UserControls` that will contain all of the views for the wizard. I also have a property/field that holds the current view. I want to create a **xaml UserControl** tag that binds to the current view property. It should change when I change the current view property (I have already implemented the `INotifyChanged` interface). The current view property will be changed by `c#`. Here is the code that I have(simplified to show whats needed), and when I run it nothing shows in the view area:

**WizardWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WizardWindow.WizardWindow"...>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Wizard Title"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Name="WizardWindowPageContent" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">


            <!--This is what I have tried but isn't working -->
            <UserControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />


        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="WizardButtons">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0">Cancel</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2">Back</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3">Next</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**WizardWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
...
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WizardWindow
{
    public partial class WizardWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // List of views in the config window
        private List<UserControl> views;

        // Current view showing in the window
        private UserControl currentView;
        public UserControl CurrentView
        {
            get { return currentView; }
            set
            {
                currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }

        // Used to keep track of the view index 
        private int viewIndex;

        public WizardWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Set the screen to the center of the screen
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

            views = new List<UserControl>();

            views.Add(new FirstWizardPage(this));

            viewIndex = 0;
            CurrentView = views[viewIndex];
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstWizardPage.xaml:**

```
<!-- This should show up in the window -->
<UserControl x:Class="WizardWindow.FirstWizardPage" ... >
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock>Lorem Ipsum ...</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**FirstWizard.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WizardWindow
{
    public partial class FirstWizardPage : UserControl
    {
        public FirstWizardPage(WizardWindow window)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The given possible duplicate, [Window vs Page vs UserControl for WPF navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation)
, is a good solution if I wanted to rewrite my program. However, it is not a solution to my exact problem. Someone else might have a similar problem and need this solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window vs Page vs UserControl for WPF navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206120/window-vs-page-vs-usercontrol-for-wpf-navigation)

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel. See [Navigation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyView"
                Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
```

It should work for you, but it's not MVVM.

Comment: This worked but I needed to have `this.DataContext = this;` in the WizardWindow.xaml.cs in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You must binding on property DataContext of your user control, if you want to use MVVM.
I Will show little example for you:

It is MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:Foo DataContext="{Binding UserControlViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

It is MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

}
```

It is MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        UserControlViewModel = new UserControlViewModel{ Name = "Hello World" };
    }
    public UserControlViewModel UserControlViewModel { get; }
}
```

It is Foo.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.Foo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> 
</Grid>
```

It is FooUsercontrolViewModel.cs

```
public class FooUserControlViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description on how to use MVVM in this context. However, I am to far into this project to rebuild everything.